Python: How to slice a 2d array to specified range of x and y values? Also how to improve this code?
I have a meshgrid given by X and Y of unequal length and a 2d array of values vx2. I want to create a sub-2d array Z from a certain xlim and ylim. I want to create a contour plot but since matplotlib only zooms into this region and doesn't rescale the contour levels to these values. But I am failing at this:
This is the code snippet. x and y are predefined coordinate arrays. vx2_d has shape (len(x),len(y)).
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

mask_x = (x >= 60) & (x <= 61.2)  
mask_y = (y >= 1.42) & (y <= 1.72)

# have to convert to numpy since I can't figure out how to create a 2d list from 2 1d lists.

mask_x_r = np.array(mask_x)[:,np.newaxis]
mask_y_r = np.array(mask_y)[np.newaxis,:]


# Combine the masks
# For some reason a simple mask_x_r * mask_y_r just gives me a 1D array.

mask = np.multiply(mask_x_r,mask_y_r )
mask =  np.reshape(mask,(len(mask_x),len(mask_y)))


Za_subregion = vx2_d[mask.tolist()]

# A simple Za_subregion = vx2_d[mask_x][mask_y] gives an error about shape not being broadcastable

print(np.shape(Za_subregion))


plt.pcolormesh(X[mask_x],Y[mask_y],Za_subregion.T,cmap=plt.cm.seismic) 
#plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,vx2_d.T,cmap=plt.cm.seismic) 
plt.xlabel("Radial distance")
plt.ylabel("Angular distance")
plt.title("Dust Vx2 Contour plot")  
plt.colorbar()
#plt.xlim(60,61.2)
#plt.ylim(1.42,1.72)
plt.show() 


Unfortunately print(np.shape(Za_subregion)) just gives me a 1d array and the whole plot naturally throws an error. What can I do fix/improve this?

Please, provide a [mre]. We don't know what x, y or vx2_d are. And we can't even surmise, since the affirmation you make in comments are unreproducible (mask_x_r*mask_y_r does produce a 2D array, not 1D, for example). Also, we can't really understand why you say that you are "forced to convert to numpy", when everything we see here is already 100% numpy. Nor why to use mask.tolist() to index that mysterious vx2_d. Anyway, that is not a guessing game. Please provide a [mre] and all information we need

Also, there should be one question per post. So, choose between that 2d slice thing, or the code improvement. Or post 2 different questions (but the "code improvement" need to be really more clarified. Improve how and what? The speed? clarity? memory? reusability?, ...
And when posting example, include only what is necessary to reproduce the problem (for example, I don't think we need the matplotlib part)

It seems to me you're overcomplicating things. You can either define mask_x = (X >= 60) & (X <= 61.2), which will give you a 2D mask (same for Y) and then combine the masks as mask = mask_x & mask_y. That mask result can be used to index X, Y, and vx2_d (assuming vx2_d is a 2D array). Alternatively, you can use your current mask_x and mask_y definitions and then create mask = mask_x[None,:] & mask_y[:,None].
